# How to append a base path to all routes handled by Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm refactoring an existing expressjs app which uses jade for UI to nextjs app. I use same app as api server as well for external apps. I have all web app routes under "/ui" which I need to move under NextJS.

Inside NextJS app, all `<Link />` and `Router.push()` need to add `/ui` like `/ui/home`, `/ui/profile` and also create **ui** folder under **pages** folder. Is there a way to redirect routes handled by nextjs to `/ui/<route here>` automatically so I don't explicitly use "ui" before every route and create **ui** folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `basePath` for all routes in Next.js. However this feature is **experimental**. It's not recommended to use in production.

*next.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    basePath: '/ui',
  },
}
```

So your directory structure would be:

```
|--pages
|  |--foo
|  |--bar
```

Link usage:

```
// will generate /ui/foo
<Link href="foo">
  <a>Foo</a>
</Link>

// will generate /ui/bar
<Link href="bar">
  <a>Bar</a>
</Link>
```

If you decide to use it, you can lock Next.js version in `package.json` because there could be breaking changes in the updates.